# GUI no longer launching after (aborted) upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, gui

I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04, but at some point during the upgrade everything (except the mouse) stopped working and I did a hard reboot. Since then, I am no longer able to start my GUI (which was starting automatically before). I am prompted the following lines:

```
[0.297156] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS  
[0.297156] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
[0.920401] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, pulling instead

/dev/nvme0n1p6: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, 1577077/21315584 files, 49750948/85248046 blocks
```

I reckon the first three do not matter as I managed to get rid of them by twicking the BIOS, but in all cases, after a couple of minutes, I am able to connect on CLI (under Ubuntu 20.04, so the upgrade didn't go though), but I cannot start a GUI. Trying startx yields:

```
/etc/X11/xinit/serverrc: 3: exec: /usr/bin/X: not found
```

Please let me know if you have any idea of what could have gone wrong, any suggestion, or need further clarifications on the situation.
Thank you!

Comment: first of all, run the update command again, since you stopped mid-update (don't do that in the future, just wait). Second, you can do `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` to reinstall all the default software that came with Ubuntu, including the desktop environment.